# ReactiveCocoa: ignore subsequent next call for a period of time after receiving a next call

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

Once I `subscribeNext` to a signal, I wish that I could ignore next calls for a period of time after I received the first next call, is there any built in method to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a built-in way to do this - you could buffer and then take the first object from the resulting array?

Comment: @powerj1984 buffering makes a delay between the happening of the user interaction and the effect that respond to it, which is not very elegant

Comment: Ah, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Is this signal firing after a button press? It sounds like either the `throttle` operator (wait for user input to finish, use the last input) or using a `RACCommand` (RAC 2.x) or an `Action` (RAC 3+). RACCommand will by default only allow one execution at a time and can be tied directly to a UIButton - it will even handle disabling the button while work is being done, and kind of sounds like what you're looking for.